# vue-nuxt проект с несколькими index.html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

Как организовать проект с несколькими точками входа? Чтоб собирались 2 сборки с общими компонентами.

Например: сайт, админка для админов, админка для клиентов. Сайт не грузит компоненты админок, а админки не грузят компоненты сайта, но построить это на одной куче node_modules

Comment: Что подразумевается под точками входа?

Comment: index.html или или vue app

Comment: Можно разграничить при помощи `middleware` и разных `latout` ?

Comment: Entrypoint называется точка входа

Comment: Где то в роутере была настройка promose для подгрузки части страниц. Т.е. по  одному пути загружается  одна "коллекция", по другому  пути - другая. Вот дока https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router#extendroutes